# iPhone leaning angle - use Gyroscope?

Tags: ios, angle, gyroscope, pitch

I would like to know how many degrees is the iPhone leaning when being held upright - that is, if I point the iPhone up, I would like to know how many degrees it is looking up at?  I think that I can use the gyroscope and core motion for this, and I think that it is **pitch** that I want, however, the **pitch** is a "rate of speed" in radians per second.  I am not really interested in how quickly a user moved the iPhone, I am just interested in the leaning angle.  So if I am pointing a phone up to take a picture, I would like to know the angle of pointing up - any ideas??

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Gyro data is in radians per second, but what you are looking for is CMMotionManager.attitude property. It shows the attitude of the object in radians relative to a some frame of reference.

create class variable motionManager and init:

```
 motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
    motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 0.1f;
    [motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] withHandler:^(CMDeviceMotion *motion, NSError *error) {
        [self processMotion:motion];
    }];
```

process the updates, you are looking for pitch, but in this sample it will show you all three values so you can play around and decide what you need:

```
    -(void)processMotion:(CMDeviceMotion*)motion {
        NSLog(@"Roll: %.2f Pitch: %.2f Yaw: %.2f", motion.attitude.roll, motion.attitude.pitch, motion.attitude.yaw);
}
```

these are Euler Angles, you also have an option to get rotationMatrix, or quaternion format. Each with their own advantages and disadvantages.